# Xamarin: send mail via Gmail when on mobile data

Tags: authentication, xamarin, mobile, gmail

I've build a Xamarin app that sends an email via the smtp-server Gmail. On my phone at home, using the wifi connection, everything works fine ... but as soon as I turn off wifi the app isn't able to login on gmail.
On my gmail account I have the security setting for "Less secure apps" enabled ... but that doesn't fix it.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue ?

```
    _smtpServer = new SmtpClient();

    _smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    _smtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("blabla@gmail.com", "********");
    _smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    _smtpServer.Port = 587;
    _smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: What error or exception do you get?  Most likely your network provider is blocking port 587 or all SMTP traffic.

Comment: That the login failed ... I also get a notification from Gmail that someone tried to login and that they blocked it.

Comment: if that's the issue then its not networking.  I don't see how you can solve this without contacting Google for more info.  If you need your app to send email I'd suggest using a third party e-mail service that provides an API